# how to register domain through ressellerclub api

Tags: php, api, curl

I am Using This to Register Domain Through API
this is my code..

```
$userid= "519473";
$apikey= "ZNmID1ypHfDQ61YKQw0GufQQ2k3HxR0Y";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/register.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'auth-userid=519473&api-key=ZNmID1ypHfDQ61YKQw0GufQQ2k3HxR0Y&domain-name=hts.in&years=1&ns=ns1.faizan.com&ns=ns2.faizan.com&customer-id=10963860&reg-contact-id=10963860&admin-contact-id=10963860&tech-contact-id=10963860&billing-contact-id=10963860&invoice-option=KeepInvoice&protect-privacy=false');
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
print($httpResponse);
```

but I am getting this error
{"status":"ERROR","message":"{techcontactid\u003dtech ContactId is not registered by you, admincontactid\u003dadmin ContactId is not registered by you, billingcontactid\u003dbilling ContactId is not registered by you, registrantcontactid\u003dregistrant ContactId is not registered by you}"}

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and I just found out the solution.

Those ContactId come from your customer but they are not customerId.

You can get ContactId and other details of your customers by use this API

http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/794

Comment: I sent `1` instead of `-1` on the `admin-contact-id` for `.UK` TLD and got this error, after I change the value to `-1` it fixed. http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/752